# What's the point of a copied / duplicate reference variable?

Tags: java, idioms

I just saw the following code:

```
public static void initElements(WebDriver driver, Object page) {
    final WebDriver driverRef = driver;
    initElements(new DefaultElementLocatorFactory(driverRef), page);
}
```

Can somebody tell me, what's the advantage of writing this instead of:

```
public static void initElements(WebDriver driver, Object page) {
    initElements(new DefaultElementLocatorFactory(driver), page);
}
```

I hope my first question here isn't too pointless and/or stupid and youi have fun answering it!

(Code quote from [org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#2tHw6m3DZzo/trunk/support/src/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/PageFactory.java&q=pagefactory%20package%3ahttp://selenium%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=84); Copyright 2007-2009 WebDriver committers; Copyright 2007-2009 Google Inc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no difference in application behavior. However such pattern might be used when:

- wanting to provide a local name of the value which is better suited in this context. Here it's `driverRef` vs `driver`, which doesn't bring any value, but in other cases it might
- wanting to make the variable accessible as a local variable for debugger. Debuggers may treat local variables and class fields differently (e.g. when presenting their values), but it's hard to justify such a change to be made permamently
- caring of readability. Here the replaced expression is simple - just `driver`, but sometimes you have a more complicated expression which would make the line too long if inlined.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I don't see any point. But I can see a point to declare variable as final. So this is going to be sufficient:

```
public static void initElements(final WebDriver driver, Object page) {
    initElements(new DefaultElementLocatorFactory(driver), page);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the 'final' keyword is the answer to your question.

final means the reference cannot be reassigned.

Comment: ... tarlog beat me to it with a better answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As already said, in the code you posted there's really no point.

One reason for making a variable `final` is when you want to use it in an anonymous inner class inside the method. A variable must be `final` to be able to be accessed inside the anonymous inner class. A somewhat silly example, just to illustrate the point:

```
public static void initElements(final WebDriver driver, final Object page) {
    // Anonymous inner class
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // The variables must be final, otherwise you can't access them here
            initElements(new DefaultElementLocatorFactory(driver), page);
        }
    };

    runnable.run();
}
```